# Поиск игнорирует содержимое таблиц

Tags: php, wordpress

Реализовал таблицу в Wordpress через плагин (PAFE Tables), но поиск по сайту не находит содержимое таблицы
[https://overstroy.com.ua/?s=кс-9](https://overstroy.com.ua/?s=%D0%BA%D1%81-9) - поиск
https://overstroy.com.ua/rings/ - страница, на которой есть таблица с этим текстом.
Пытался сделать по инструкции с https://oddstyle.ru/wordpress-2/stati-wordpress/sozdaem-svoj-sobstvennyj-poisk-v-wordpress.html и вставил в searchform.php`<input type="hidden" value="widget" name="pafe-table.default" />` Вы не могли бы посмотреть, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что такое PAFE Tables? Такого плагина нет в оф каталоге и даже не гуглится.

Comment: Piotnet Addons For Elementor - PAFE. В нем есть элемент таблиц - Table

Comment: Тогда с вопросами по элементору - к его создателям.

Answer (score -2):

Итог: SeVlad неправ, проблема вообще не в элементоре и его создателях. Владелец сайта сам, никого не предупредив, установил отдельный плагин для поиска Relevanssi. Деактивировал плагин - все отлично заработало.

Comment: Это ты не прав - телепатов тут нет.